# How to get user's first name without access token when opening the 'feed' dialog?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

According to [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/), you can get some user data without an access token. When I try this:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

I get the following object:

```
{ error: {
    message: "An active access token ...about the current user.",
    type: "OAuthException"
} }
```

What's wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I ended "discovering" in other source codes (because it's not in the docs) that you can use a placeholder called `{*actor*}`.
It worked this way:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  link: '<? echo $app['url'] ?>',
  name: $poll.find('.pollQuestionContainer .pollQuestion').text(),
  caption: '{*actor*} answered ' + selected_answer,
  description: 'TV Channel',
  properties: answers
});
```